# Entity framework DbContext ctx populating null values for newly altered table columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to get values from `ObservationPrograms` table using EF ctx. I got all values in ctx except `Op_DetailUniqueId` and `IsClosed` columns. These two columns are newly altered with table and model is updated for these two columns. I have updated model many times but null values are populating.

[values retrieved from DB in ctx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMytw.png)

[Actual values in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zl6d.png)

Comment: Not resolved after refreshing model or delete and add table in model once again.

Answer (score 0):

I got some similar problems in my project and the solution was to delete the updated table from my model and insert the same table again.

This worked for me even i "refreshed" the tables after updating them in the db. (also dont forget to actually save ur model after that).